# Choose dependency for injection using Kiwi in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-injection, kiwi

I have the following code:

```
KiwiContainer()
      ..registerFactory((c) => GetOrderListOfItemsUseCase(
          repository: c<ShopRepository>()))
```

The problem here is that the `GetOrderListOfItemsUseCase` requires an instance of `IProfileRepository` which the `ShopProfileRepository` extends from.

**NOTE**: `IProfleRepository` is extended by `IUserProfileRepository` and `IShopProfileRepository`.

UPDATE: I have the following factories:

```
..registerFactory<IShopRepository>((c) => c<ShopRepository>())
..registerFactory<IUserProfileRepository>((c) => c<UserProfileRepository>())
```

The thing is that I want to dynamically inject the proper dependency for `GetUserLocationsUseCase`.

```
..registerFactory(
          (c) => GetUserLocationsUseCase(repository: c<IProfileRepository>()))
```

how can I inject in the code the proper subtype of  `IProfileRepository` whether it `IShopRepository` or `IUserProfileRepository`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dinamically inject either `UserProfileRepository` or `ShopProfileRepository` you should register the one you are going to use via its supertype.

```dart
KiwiContainer()
      ..registerFactory<IProfleRepository>((c) => ShopProfileRepository())
      ..registerFactory((c) => GetOrderListOfItemsUseCase(
          repository: c<IProfleRepository>()))
```

And obtain it via its supertype too, like in the snippet.